# combining two graph i tensorflow and optimze the middle model only

Tags: python, tensorflow, autoencoder

I have auto-encoder (E1 - D1) trained already 
Now I want another auto-encoder lets call it (E2 - D2)

so the model its like that E1 -> E2 -> D2 -> D1 where the model optimize E2 D2 only by using output of D1 and input to E1

E1 -> 5 CNN layers + 1 FC (already trained)

E2 -> 5 CNN layers + 1 FC

D2 -> 5 DeCNN layers + 1 FC

D1 -> 5 DeCNN layers + 1 FC (already trained)

Note E1 D1 already trained (blue in the image)

please see the image

[image]

I want to use X (input) Y (output) to optimize only E2 D2

Comment: It is unclear what you mean. Are you saying you have an auto-encoder with trained weights, and want to add a second auto-encoder layer to create a stacked auto-encoder network with 2 layers?

Comment: hi , I made it clear, check please the question

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this in tensorflow would be to first train E1 and D1 (already done). And then extract and store the values of the `tf.Variables` (weights and biases) for these networks, then create an entirely new network with structure that encompasses all of the auto-encoders described above, and inject the extracted weight values back into the new network.

You can do this by traning the E1 and D1 networks and then calling [tf.get_tensor_by_name](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Graph#get_tensor_by_name) within the session to extract the weight values as numpy arrays. These can then be saved for later using [np.save](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html).

Create your new full network with all the desired layers:

5 CNN layers + 1 FC + 5 CNN layers + 1 FC + 5 DeCNN layers + 1 FC 5 DeCNN layers + 1 FC

And then you can initialise the values of the [tf.Variables](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable) in the E1 and D1 layers to the values saved earlier, by loading the previously saved values using [np.load](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.load.html) and then passing these to your tf.Variables as the `<initial-value>` argument described [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable).

You can set these restored tf.Variables to untrainable so that they remain fixed during the rest of the training.

Comment: hi finley, I followed your steps and I think it works (thanx for that ) however one thing I need help about which is I have to process y_prediction the final output before loss and optimization step . I tried each times shows me error optimization issue cant back propagation

Comment: The first thing to check here would be that every step you have made in your network is a tensorflow operation (starting with `tf.`). Tensorflow operations have inbuilt methods to automatically compute the differentials required for back propagation gradient calculations, and this error implies that it cannot compute these gradients. For example, using a numpy operation as part of your tensorflow graph could cause this.

Comment: A s for how to process `y_prediction`, it depends on the type of network you have. If you can provide a link to your code I will have a look at it for you and see if I can see what the issue is.